# NextJs dynamic path variables do not appear in router.query on initial page load, when basePath is changed and middleware exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a **NextJS** application, recently I changed the **basePath** of my application in next.config.js file just added the basePath key with my desired path.

After doing that I noticed **dynamic path variables** that were passed through slugs (e.g. /something/[id].js) are not getting loaded initially in next's router.query (in this case id), but after a full page reload it appears perfectly. Surprisingly the variables were also accessible in the getServerSideProp's context.

Now this only happens if I have a **middleware** file (middleware.js) in my project. This issue happens even if I do nothing in the middleware.